# Safe to remove this: <?php comments_template(); ?> when using a 3rd Party Comment App?

Tags: comments

I am using Disqus for my comments on WordPress.

I am correct in thinking that I can remove this line or is that just plain wrong? I am referring to this:

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

I am probably wrong because how else would the comments know where to load right?

Comment: It probably depends on how Disqus is hooking into your site, but I'd guess that is uses it to position the Comments. But you can try - worst thing is you need to re-add the template tag.

Comment: why not to ask disqus support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Disqus plugin core:

```
// Only replace comments if the disqus_forum_url option is set.
add_filter('comments_template', 'dsq_comments_template');
```

Which certainly implies that Disqus uses the `<?php comments_template(); ?>` include to include it's own files, so I would advise leaving it where it is :)